# List returns NULL to MVC Controller when editing any page other than Page 1 in MVC view which has Pagination rendered by Jquery Datatables

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I am using ASP.Net MVC 5 with C#. My List returns NULL from View to MVC controller when editing any page other than Page 1 in MVC view which has pagination rendered by Jquery Datatables. When I edit records on Page 1, I am able to successfully save changes but when I edit Page 2 and other pages, I get `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

The error thrown is like this:

```
Server Error in '/TMS' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 76:             if (ModelState.IsValid)
Line 77:             {                
Line 78:                 foreach (var i in tblBulkDispatchList)
Line 79:                 {
Line 80:                     var c = db.tblBulkDispatches.Where(a => a.BulkDispatchId.Equals(i.BulkDispatchId)).FirstOrDefault();

Source File: c:\xxx\yyy\zzz\BulkDispatchController.cs    Line: 78 

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   TMS.Controllers.BulkDispatchController.BulkDispatchEdit(List`1 tblBulkDispatchList) in c:\xxx\yyy\zzz\BulkDispatchController.cs:78
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +104
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +156
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9667388
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

My controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult BulkDispatchEdit(List<tblBulkDispatch> tblBulkDispatchList)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {                
                foreach (var i in tblBulkDispatchList)
                {
                    var c = db.tblBulkDispatches.Where(a => a.BulkDispatchId.Equals(i.BulkDispatchId)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (c != null)
                    {
                        c.AuditNumbers = i.AuditNumbers;                        
                    }
                }
                db.SaveChanges();

                ViewBag.Message = "Successfully Updated.";
                return View(tblBulkDispatchList);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Failed ! Please try again.";
                return View(tblBulkDispatchList);
            }
        }
```

My MVC view looks like this:

```
@model List<TMS.Models.tblBulkDispatch>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Update Audit Numbers";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }

<link href="~/Content/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<h2>Update Audit Numbers</h2>

<br /> @using (@Html.BeginForm("BulkDispatchEdit", "BulkDispatch", FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <table class="table" id="tblData">
        <thead>
            <tr>                
                <th></th>
                <th>Student ID:</th>
                <th>Last Name:</th>
                <th>Other Names:</th>
                <th>Requester:</th>
                <th>Date Recorded:</th>
                <th>Audit Numbers:</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>            
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td> 
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].BulkDispatchId)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].StudentId)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].LastName)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].OtherNames)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Requester)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].CreatedDate)                        
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].CreatedBy)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].StudentId)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].LastName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].OtherNames)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Requester)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].CreatedDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].AuditNumbers)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].AuditNumbers)                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>

    </table>

    <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
    </div>

    <p style="color:green; font-size:12px;">
        @ViewBag.Message
    </p> }

@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") }

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> <script src="~/Scripts/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script> <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#tblData").DataTable();
    }) </script>
```

Comment: Can you mark which line throwing NRE exception during changing datatable pages? Also posting stack trace of the error may help investigate problem source.

Comment: Hi Tetsuya...I have edited the question to show the Stack trace...The reason it's null is because when someone clicks on Page 2 or any other page except for Page 1, the Datatable seems to lose track on the Objects